# Difference between spanning set and a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can anybody please shed some light on the difference between a spanning set and a basis?

Comment: A spanning set does not need to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *basis* is a spanning set that is also *linearly independent*.

For example, consider the vector space $\mathbb{P}$ of all linear polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, of the form
$$
\mathbb{P} = \{a+bx|a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Let $\vec{u} = 1, \vec{v} = x, \vec{w} = 1+x$ and let $S = \left\{\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\right\}$.

Note that $S$ spans $\mathbb{P}$, but it not linearly independent, hence $S$ is **not** a basis for $\mathbb{P}$. To get a basis, take any 2 elements of $S$.